# How to terminate transmission-cli

Tags: ruby, linux, bitcoin, transmission, torrent

I am using ruby script to download bitcoin bootstrap.dat file, This file can only be downloaded by using torrent client so to download on command line i am using following ruby demo script:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby env
`transmission-cli https://bitcoin.org/bin/blockchain/bootstrap.dat.torrent`
```

Now i run that script

```
root@master:~# ruby demo
```

But that script hangs because above transmission downloads torrents file perfectly but after that it start to seeding and uploading and never terminate automatically, Is there any way i can terminate this using my script?

Is there any way by which i can send kill or termination signal after torrent download finished?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `-f, -finish <script>` which executes a script when the download is completed:

```
tmpfile=$(mktemp)
chmod a+x $tmpfile
echo "killall transmission-cli" > $tmpfile
transmission-cli -f $tmpfile your.torrent
```

You could also use [`rtorrent`](http://harbhag.wordpress.com/2010/06/30/tutorial-using-rtorrent-on-linux-like-a-pro/) which has more options.

Comment: I got  error executing script "killall transmission-cli": No such file or directory, Can you provide correct way here?

Comment: In case you want to run more downloads, it may make sense to use the PID instead, something like: `killfile=$(mktemp); transmission-cli -f "$killfile" -ep -u 64 -p $(python -c 'import random; print(random.randint(1024,65535))') "$i" &
    echo 'kill '$(jobs -p | tail -1)'; rm -f "$0"' > "$killfile"; chmod +x "$killfile"`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the script, I have it setup like this:

```
tmpfile=$(mktemp)
chmod a+x $tmpfile
echo "paplay /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/complete.oga && killall transmission-cli" > $tmpfile
transmission-cli -f $tmpfile  "$(xclip -o -selection clipboard)"
```

How would I add a notification sound like this:

paplay /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/complete.oga

So it goes off when it's finished? Just asking, I'm not a coder or script writer, I just mainly copy and paste my scripts.

Nevermind, I figured it out, I set it up like this:

```
tmpfile=$(mktemp) chmod a+x $tmpfile echo "paplay/usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/complete.oga && killall transmission-cli" > $tmpfile 
transmission-cli -f $tmpfile "$(xclip -o selection clipboard)"
```